# SQL Server history tracking of a table with multiple same referencing column

Tags: sql-server-2008, history, self-reference, self-referencing-table

In my database design, I'm tracking history with triggers. First of all, I have a base table `Goods` with the following columns:

```
Tablename: Goods
COLUMN1PK: GoodID
COLUMN2: ArticleCode
COLUMN3: Amount
```

I want to track all operations made on the goods, like insert, delete or replace (not necessarily the changed values of the columns) . There can be an insert, an update, a delete or a replacement of a good. For example, `GoodID 1` has reached it's lifetime and getting replaced by `GoodID 2`. To be able to capture this information, I can't see any other option than having a second column in the history table referencing to the same `GoodID` from the table `Goods`

My history table would be:

```
Tablename: GoodsHistory
COLUMN1PK: GoodHistoryID
COLUMN2: ChangedBy
COLUMN3: DateChanged
COLUMN4: ActionType (like inserted, updated, replaced or deleted)
COLUMN5FK: GoodID (capture any insert/update/'fake'-delete operation)
COLUMN6FK: ReplacedByGoodID (capture the `GoodID` that is the replaced `GoodID`)
```

See this record-set for an example of history data:

```
COLUMN1PK:  |  1          |  2           |  3           |  4
COLUMN2:    |  User1      |  User1       |  User1       |  User2
COLUMN3:    |  10/12/2012 |  12/16/2014  |  12/16/2014  |  12/16/2014
COLUMN4:    |  Inserted   |  Inserted    |  Replaced    |  Inserted
COLUMN5FK:  |  1          |  2           |  1           |  3
COLUMN6FK:  |  NULL       |  NULL        |  2           |  NULL
```

Short explanation: `GoodID 1` exists since 2 years, and today `User1` created a new `GoodID` and replaced the old one with the new one. Also, a `User2` created a new `GoodID 3`.

I'm working in SQL Server 2008 R2, and SQL don't like multiple cascading paths. The cascading path exists because `COLUMN5FK` and `COLUMN6FK` both refer to `GoodID`.
Only 1 of the two relationships allow a `Cascade` while the other is forced to take `No action` upon `Update/Delete` operations, resulting in non delete-able Goods if both `FK-relationships`'s are set. (So in this case, I cannot update/delete `GoodID 1` and `2`.)

A workaround would be a trigger. Since I have a few tables that have the same setup, this would require me to create/edit triggers for each table that tracks history this same way, and I'm afraid of additional overhead as well as managing problems upon database schema changes.

So my question is actually if there are other, maybe smarter design/solutions for this kind of information gathering, or if I should stick with this one due to the limitations of SQL Server.

Comment: Do you really need cascade and fk's on history table. From what i see if you delete goods, then records from history also deleted, not marked as deleted in Col4

Comment: PK's won't be updated so for that reason they really don't. But once a Good gets permanently deleted it needs to be deleted from the history as well

Comment: As workaround i can suggest inserting 2 records for replace, having column for self-reference to another record.

Comment: I have tried that as well, I forgot to mention. SQL also don't allow Cascade upon self reference. So I'm forced to delete in the right order or a trigger on the history table

Comment: IMHO Than you need something more than one table for history, First will keep records for your goods, and main table will have references.
e.g. GoodsActions {Id, GoodId, Action} / GoodsHistory {UserId, GoodsActionsId, SetId} where SetId will aggregate single history entry for logical operations.

Comment: I guess that's the only option left indeed, haven't thought about it. Can you post this in a form of an answer so I can close the question? And thank you, I will go with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO Than you need something more than one table for history, First will keep records for your goods, and main table will have references. e.g.

```
GoodsActions {Id, GoodId, Action} 
GoodsHistory {UserId, GoodsActionsId, SetId}
```

where SetId will aggregate single history entry for logical operations.